# Missing a single day

Tags: sql, sql-server

My database has two tables, a car table and a wheel table.
I'm trying to find the number of wheels that meet a certain condition over a range of days, but some days are not included in the output.

Here is the query:

```
USE CarDB
SELECT MONTH(c.DateTime1) 'Month',
       DAY(c.DateTime1) 'Day',
       COUNT(w.ID) 'Wheels'
  FROM tblCar c
 INNER JOIN tblWheel w
    ON c.ID = w.CarID
 WHERE c.DateTime1 BETWEEN '05/01/2013' AND '06/04/2013'
   AND w.Measurement < 18
 GROUP BY MONTH(c.DateTime1), DAY(c.DateTime1)
 ORDER BY [ Month ], [ Day ]
GO
```

The output results seem to be correct, but days with 0 wheels do not show up. For example:

Sample Current Output:

```
Month Day Wheels
2     1   7
2     2   4
2     3   2 -- 2/4 is missing
2     5   9
```

Sample Desired Ouput:

```
Month Day Wheels
2     1   7
2     2   4
2     3   2
2     4   0
2     5   9
```

I also tried a left join but it didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right track with a `LEFT JOIN`

Try run your query with this kind of outer join but remove your `WHERE` clause. Notice anything?

What's happening is that the join is applied and then the where clause removes the values that don't match the criteria. All this happens before the group by, meaning the cars are excluded.

Here's one method for you:

```
SELECT Year(cars.datetime1) As the_year
     , Month(cars.datetime1) As the_month
     , Day(cars.datetime1) As the_day
     , Count(wheels.id) As wheels
FROM   (
        SELECT id
             , datetime1
        FROM   tblcar
        WHERE  datetime1 BETWEEN '2013-01-05' AND '2013-04-06'
       ) As cars
 LEFT
  JOIN tblwheels As wheels
    ON wheels.carid = cars.id
```

What's different this time round is that we're limiting the results of the car table *before* we join to the wheels table.

Comment: Interestingly enough, I get the same output with this as @FrankPI's answer. I have all of the days now, but the wheel count is way off.

Comment: I got this to work by making this modification: `ON wheels.carid = cars.id AND wheels.Measurement < 18`.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`:

```
USE CarDB

SELECT MONTH (c.DateTime1) 'Month', DAY (c.DateTime1) 'Day', COUNT (w.ID) 'Wheels'
FROM tblCar c LEFT OUTER JOIN tblWheel w ON c.ID = w.CarID
WHERE c.DateTime1 BETWEEN '05/01/2013' AND '06/04/2013'
  AND (w.Measurement IS NULL OR w.Measurement < 18)
GROUP BY MONTH (c.DateTime1), DAY (c.DateTime1)
ORDER BY [Month], [Day]
GO
```

Aand then, you need to adapt the WHERE condition, as you want to keep the rows with `w.Measurement` being `NULL` due to the OUTER join.

Comment: This gives me the correct date range, but my wheel count per day is totally off.

Comment: @jliv902 Can you give an example where the "wheel count per day is totally off"? What are the records in both tables involved in that count, and which count do you expect?

Comment: I would expect the new and old query to give the same results for the wheel counts that are non-zero. Most of my wheel counts from the old query are in the single or double digits. Now my wheel counts are in the thousands for each day. Please let me know if I can clarify this situation any further.

Comment: @jliv902 Looking at my query, I found an error: There need to be parentheses around the `w.Measurement IS NULL OR w.Measurement < 18`, as `AND` has higher precedence in SQL than `OR`.

Comment: I actually used parentheses when I ran the query. I finally got this to work with some minor modifications to @gvee's answer. Thank you for your help though.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the join and change your select to this:

```
SELECT MONTH (c.DateTime1) 'Month', DAY (c.DateTime1) 'Day', isnull(select top 1 (select COUNT from tblWheel where id = tblCar.ID and Measurement < 18), 0)  'Wheels'
```